# Printing unique values from an .xlsx file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel file that contains data. The column I'm interested in (column A) either contains a blank cell, the single character "Y", the word "Runmode" or a unique value that I'm interested in.

I only want to pull out the unique value and print it to the console, but am having trouble.

I'm using openpyxl to parse the .xlsx file.

```
    wb = load_workbook(location + '\\' + suite)
    data_sheet = wb['Data']
    for i in range(1, data_sheet.max_row + 1):
        cell_value = data_sheet['A' + str(i)].value
        if cell_value is not 'Y' and cell_value is not 'Runmode' and cell_value is not None:
            print(cell_value == 'Runmode')
            print(repr(cell_value), cell_value, 'success')
```

The output is printing 'Runmode' even though it equates True to a value that I'm telling my script to ignore. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test for equality of strings using `==`, as you are doing in your print statement. Or at least you should make your print statement:

```
print(cell_value is 'Runmode')
```

to make sure you are checking the same thing.

This discrepancy between `is` and `==` e.g happens if `cell_value` is unicode and you are using Python 2.7.

As Steven Rumbalski pointed out you better rewrite the `if` statement to:

```
  if cell_value not in ('Runmode', 'Y', None):
```